# flutter video_thumbnail Work with isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, isolation, video-thumbnails

I am trying to use the video_thumbnail library inside the Isolae, when it fails to get a thumbnail, an error occurs that cancels the isolate work without giving any output , and the FutureBuilder remains in the waiting state and does not go to the error state or to any other state.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4wA2.png)

and this is my code

```
 void videoThumpIsolateMain(IsolateParameters isolateParameters) async {
  print(isolateParameters.file.path);
  if (isolateParameters.rootIsolateToken != null) {
    BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized(
        isolateParameters.rootIsolateToken!);
    try {
      Directory vidDirectory = await DirectoryInTemporary.createVideosImageDirectory();
      String data = await VideoInfo.basicThumbnail(
        videoPath: isolateParameters.file.path,
        videoName: isolateParameters.file.name,
        directory: vidDirectory,
      ) ?? 'error';

      isolateParameters.sendPort.send(data);
      Isolate.exit();
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      isolateParameters.sendPort.send('error');
      Isolate.exit();
    }
  } else {
    isolateParameters.sendPort.send('error');
    Isolate.exit();
  }
}


Future<String> getThumpDataInIsolate({
  required context,
  required FileElement file,
  required List<FileElement> refList,
}) async {
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort('thump');
  try {
    void Function(IsolateParameters) entryPoint;
    if (file.fileType == FileType.video) {
      entryPoint = videoThumpIsolateMain;
    } else {
      entryPoint = imageThumpIsolateMain;
    }
    await Isolate.spawn(
        entryPoint,
        onError: receivePort.sendPort,
        IsolateParameters(
            rootIsolateToken: RootIsolateToken.instance,
            sendPort: receivePort.sendPort,
            refList: refList,
            file: file));
    dynamic outPut = await receivePort.first;
    if (outPut is String) {
      file.imagePath = outPut;
      return outPut;
    } else {
      file.imagePath = 'error';
      return 'error';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
    file.imagePath = 'error';
    return 'error';
  }
}
```

and this is  basicThumbnail frome video_thumbnail  package

```
static Future<String?> basicThumbnail({
    required String videoPath,
    required String videoName,
    required Directory directory,
  }) async {
    String thumbnailFilePath =
        thumbnailPath(videoName: videoName, directory: directory);
    bool thumbnailFileExists = await File(thumbnailFilePath).exists();
    if (thumbnailFileExists) {
      return thumbnailFilePath;
    } else {
      try{
        String? thumbnail = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile(
          timeMs: 500,
          video: videoPath,
          thumbnailPath: directory.path,
          imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
          quality: 50,
        );
        if(thumbnail != null && thumbnail.isNotEmpty) {
          return thumbnail;
        }else{
          throw('error');
        }
      }catch(e){
        throw('error $e');
      }

    }
  }
```

I tried using video_compress inside isolatie as an alternative but it doesn't work inside isolate.